# How are parish names traditionally chosen?

Tags: catholicism, church-local, catholic-parishes

We're undergoing a big flip in the diocese of Madison and almost all the that were churches canonical parishes before are becoming part of a bigger grouping of churches within an expanded parish boundary.

There's lots of hubbub about what we're going to name the new parish, but I don't know that anybody in the parish itself has much of a say over such things.  Are they decided by committee, from above, by popular opinion, by tradition (do we just keep the name of the central parish church) or what?

Comment: Quick googling found [this short answer](https://www.lincolndiocese.org/news/diocesan-news/12303-ask-the-register-how-is-a-parish-named) to a similar question (from Lincoln, Nebraska).  Relevant *Wikipedia* article section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parish_(Catholic_Church)#Merger_and_suppression) which includes how to resolve conflict over merger and suppression.